# SQL query to get N elements of a table with repeated data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns data in this format

`| Name   | SomeData    | MoreStuff     |
|--------|-------------|---------------|
| asset1 | I need this | And also this |
| asset1 | I need this | And also this |
| asset1 | I need this | And also this |
| asset2 | I need this | And also this |
| asset2 | I need this | And also this |
| asset3 | I need this | And also this |
| asset3 | I need this | And also this |
| asset3 | I need this | And also this |
| asset4 | I need this | And also this |
| asset5 | I need this | And also this |
| asset5 | I need this | And also this |
| ...... | ........... | ............. |`

Let's say that I need 20 different assets, but also the data of each row. 
A "LIMIT" here won't work and with a "GROUP BY" neither.

What other options do I have?

----- Edit ----

For example, if I need 3 differents assets the output should be

`| Name   | SomeData    | MoreStuff     |
|--------|-------------|---------------|
| asset1 | I need this | And also this |
| asset1 | I need this | And also this |
| asset1 | I need this | And also this |
| asset2 | I need this | And also this |
| asset2 | I need this | And also this |
| asset3 | I need this | And also this |
| asset3 | I need this | And also this |
| asset3 | I need this | And also this |`

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: What about `Limit` with `Distinct`?

Comment: Added the expected output. How works LIMIT with DISCTINCT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired result set by doing a join to same table but with limited rows like

```
select a.*
from demo a
join (
  select distinct Name
  from demo 
  order by Name
  limit 3
) b on a.Name = b.Name
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/079ea/1)

Answer (score 1):

This will get the rows of the first 3 assets without having to use a self-join:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5ec26f/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  Name      VARCHAR(20),
  SomeData  VARCHAR(20),
  MoreStuff VARCHAR(20)
);


INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'asset4', 'I need this', 'And also this' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'asset5', 'I need this', 'And also this' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'asset2', 'I need this', 'And also this' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'asset3', 'I need this', 'And also this' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'asset1', 'I need this', 'And also this' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'asset3', 'I need this', 'And also this' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'asset2', 'I need this', 'And also this' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'asset1', 'I need this', 'And also this' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'asset1', 'I need this', 'And also this' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'asset3', 'I need this', 'And also this' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'asset5', 'I need this', 'And also this' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Name, SomeData, MoreStuff
FROM   (
  SELECT @asset_num := IF( @prev_name = t.name, @asset_num, @asset_num + 1 ) AS an,
         t.*,
         @prev_name := Name
  FROM   table_name t
         CROSS JOIN
         ( SELECT @prev_name := '', @asset_num := 0 ) r
  ORDER BY Name
) t
WHERE an <= 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5ec26f/3/0)**:

```
|   Name |    SomeData |     MoreStuff |
|--------|-------------|---------------|
| asset1 | I need this | And also this |
| asset1 | I need this | And also this |
| asset1 | I need this | And also this |
| asset2 | I need this | And also this |
| asset2 | I need this | And also this |
| asset3 | I need this | And also this |
| asset3 | I need this | And also this |
| asset3 | I need this | And also this |
```

Comment: That query works on sql fiddle but on my environment it only return one row by name, I don't understand why, the table only have more columns...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select *
from TABLE
where Name in (
    select distinct Name 
    from TABLE
    limit 3
)
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work, my server is in (disgracefully) 5.6 version

Answer (score 0):

This will give you maximum 3 rows for each asset. You can change 3 to any number, then you will get that much rows for each asset.

```
SELECT Name, SomeData, MoreStuff
FROM (
       SELECT  @name_number := IF(@Name = Name, @name_number + 1, 1) AS name_number, 
               @Name := Name as Name, SomeData, MoreStuff
       FROM 
              (SELECT @name_number := 1) x, 
              (SELECT SomeData, MoreStuff, @Name := Name as Name FROM your_table ORDER BY Name) y
      ) z
WHERE name_number <= 3;
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo Here!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c04f/6)